# JavaScript Attribute Values not updating Bootstrap styles

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I created a button from an embedded script, but the added Bootstrap style "btn btn-success" does not show a green button.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <main>
    </main>
    <aside>
        <hr>
    <button onclick="createElementBtn();">Create a button</button><br />
    </aside>
</div>  <!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function createElementBtn(){
        var bodyEl = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var mainEl = bodyEl.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
        var btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.type='button';
        btn.class='btn btn-success';
        btn.innerHTML='Basic Button';
        mainEl.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn.classList.add('btn');
btn.classList.add('btn-success');
```

or by className:

```
btn.className = 'btn btn-success';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the `className` property of the element instead of defining a  `class` property.

```
btn.className = 'btn btn-success';
```